# Angular4 background image

Tags: angular, image, background-image

I am trying to make a background image to div. but image not showing. here is my code.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image' : imageresult.pictureUrl}"> some content here! </div>
```

Comment: What does it show in the console of your webbrowser? Do you get an error? Is the path correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and be sure that you have added your assets in angular-cli.json

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + imageresult.pictureUrl+ ')'}"
```