# ngStyle background-image

Tags: html, angular

I have the following problem. I have a component that has @Input string value that is a link to the image.

In my HTML file I have:

```
<div class="parallax" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url({{parallaxImage}})'}"></div>
```

but it's clearly not working (there is an error and page is not rendered at all). What syntax should I use to achieve my goal? I also tried to wrap this into function:

.ts file

```
  getParallaxImage(){
    return "'url(" + this.parallaxImage + ")'";
  }
```

.html file

```
<div class="parallax" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getParallaxImage()}"></div>
```

Now, page is rendered but background-image is not set.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50037677/4399281

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="parallax" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ parallaxImage+')'}"></div>
```

or

```
 getParallaxImage(){
    return "url(" + this.parallaxImage + ")";
  }
```

Both solutions will work now, use as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
[style.background-image]="'url(' + parallaxImage + ')'"
```